Subquery Condition In Codeigniter 4
Any idea how to convert query below into Codeigniter?
select agency from agency where agency not in (SELECT agency FROM trip where trip_type = 'local trip' group by trip_type, agency having count(agency)=(select count(*) from role));

Tried but failed. Please help

I got the idea from codeigniter select
$db = \Config\Database::connect();    
$trip_type = $this->request->getVar('trip_type');

$query = $db->query("select agency from agency where agency not in (SELECT agency FROM trip where trip_type = '".$trip_type."' group by trip_type, agency having count(agency)=(select count(*) from role));");

$results = $query->getResultArray();


$this->db->select('agency');
$this->db->from('agency');
$this->db->where_not_in('agency', function($subquery) {
    $subquery->select('agency');
    $subquery->from('trip');
    $subquery->where('trip_type', 'local trip');
    $subquery->group_by('trip_type, agency');
    $subquery->having('count(agency)', '(select count(*) from role)', false);
});
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();

